# Names of all Gambits

Tags: gambits

I am interested in knowing the names and moves for all named gambits in chess.

If anyone has such a list or knows where I can find one please do pass it on to me. Please be sure to include names of gambits that black plays as well as white and all counter gambits.

Comment: One of the most overlooked is the Dodd Gambit. When you're in a losing position, grab the board and fling it and all the pieces across the room and yell "Dodd Gambit!". Very effective.

Comment: @PeteBecker, in Russia we call it `Chinese draw`. :)

Comment: This question is too broad. You should delete it and ask a separate question for **each of the gambits** you are interested in. There is no way that **all** the moves of a gambit can be **briefly listed**, not to mention that you ask us to do this **for every known gambit and counter-gambit.**

Comment: A simple Google search came up with [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_gambits) as a result. Seems like a good place to start.

Comment: There is no authority on opening names, so giving an exhaustive list is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet will be the [ECO (or Encyclopedia of Chess Openings)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopaedia_of_Chess_Openings)

The following is a complete list of all gambits in the ECO.

- **Polish Gambit** 1. e4 b5
- **Wing Gambit** 1. e4 c5 2. b4
- **Ware Gambit** 1. a4 e5 2. a5 d5 3. e3 f5 4. a6
- **Birmingham Gambit** 1. b4 c5
- **Schuhler Gambit** 1. b4 c6 2. Bb2 a5 3. b5 cxb5 4. e4
- **Wolferts Gambit** 1. b4 e5 2. Bb2 c5
- **Englund Gambit** 1. d4 e5
- **Budapest Gambit** 1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e5
- **Benko Gambit** 1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. d5 b5
- **Staunton Gambit** 1. d4 f5 2. e4
- **Smith-Morra Gambit** 1. e4 c5 2. d4 cxd4 3. c3
- **Danish Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. d4 exd4 3. c3
- **Vienna Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nf6 3. f4
- **King's Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. f4
- **Quaade Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. Nf3 g5 4. Nc3
- **Kieseritsky Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nf6 3. Bc4 Nxe4 4. Nf3
- **Rice Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. Nf3 g5 4. h4 g4 5. Ne5 Nf6 6. Bc4 d5 7. exd5 Bd6 8. 0-0
- **Elephant Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 d5
- **Latvian Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 f5
- **Irish Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Nxe5?
- **Halloween Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Nxe5?!
- **Blackburne Shilling Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Nd4
- **Italian Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. d4
- **Rousseau Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 f5
- **Evans Gambit** 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. b4
- **Blackmar–Diemer Gambit** 1. d4 d5 2. e4 dxe4 3. Nc3
- **Queen's Gambit** 1. d4 d5 2. c4
- **Grünfeld Gambit** 1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 d5 4. Bf4 Bg7 5. e3 0-0

Comment: How about the Albin Counter-Gambit? Or From's Gambit against the Bird? I'm sure there are lots more...

Comment: @Alan - Agreed.  I would have invested more effort into the answer, but unfortunately, the question was Closed before I could finish my work.